# Can I use a second controller to frame my photo mode shots if I'm using a racing wheel?

Tags: controllers, forza-horizon

Title basically says it all.  The biggest problem I'm having is controlling the yaw, as in I can't with the racing wheel (the official Microsoft one from a few years back).  I also can't control the height from which the photo is taken, which could be useful as well.

What I really want to be able to do is use a regular controller for photo mode, and then switch back to my racing wheel for all the driving.  The gear shift paddles (LB and RB) don't do anything, and I didn't think to try the peddles.  How is this possible, if it even is possible?

Comment: Have you tried to just disconnect your racing wheel, connecting a standard controller in its place temporarily to take the picture, then swapping them back out?

Comment: Yes, I believe that was one of the first things I tried.  The controller connected as second player, and Forza wouldn't accept input from it.

Comment: What I meant is to hit start, disconnect your racing wheel - so your xbox will prompt you to reconnect a controller (as you are still logged in) and now connect your standard controller.  That way the controller should connect back as player 1.

Comment: Yes, I think that's what I tried.  IIRC, the controller still came up as second player even though the racing wheel was disconnected.  I'll have to try it again when I get back to my place.